# Statement that isn't a full-expression

Tags: c++, expression, raii, temporary-objects

It is often heard that in C++ temporary objects get deconstructed at the end of the *full-expression*. A *full-expression* is defined to be an expression that isn't a sub-expression of some other expression. This sounds very similar to the notion of a *statement* to me.

So my questions are: If I append a semi-colon to a *full-expression*, will it always be a *statement*? Can one arrive at every *full-expression* by taking some *statement* with a semi-colon at the end, and removing that semi-colon? Can I assume that every temporary will live until the end of its *statement*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a statement that is longer than the lifetime of a contained temporary:

```
if (T() == T())
  foo();
```

The two temporaries created by the expression in the *condition* are destroyed at the end of the full-expression and are no longer alive when the *statement* (`foo();`) executes.

Note that for any expression *`e`*, *`e`*`;` is a statement (namely an *expression statement*, see [stmt.expr]).

Comment: Hmm, interesting. But what about the first two questions? Are there examples that don't involve any kind of *compound-statement*?

Comment: @TobiasBrüll: Updated.

Comment: Aww, you just removed the curly braces! Although, this may be technically correct, that's not what I meant. :)

Comment: @TobiasBrüll: Please ask what you mean to ask :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB Can you relate anything to the other two questions then? If I append a semi-colon to a full-expression, will it...

Comment: @TobiasBrüll: The question is a bit weird. If you literally just appended a semicolon to a full-expression, you'd probably get a syntax error. But indeed for any expression `e`, `e;` is a statement by [stmt.expr].