# How to comprehend "Temporary objs are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression"?Could anyone make it clear by some simple example?

Tags: c++, temporary-objects

As per the documentation(), which says:

> When an implementation introduces a temporary object of a class that
>   has a non-trivial constructor ([class.default.ctor],
>   [class.copy.ctor]), it shall ensure that a constructor is called for
>   the temporary object. Similarly, the destructor shall be called for a
>   temporary with a non-trivial destructor ([class.dtor]). Temporary
>   objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the
>   full-expression ([intro.execution]) that (lexically) contains the
>   point where they were created. This is true even if that evaluation
>   ends in throwing an exception. The value computations and side effects
>   of destroying a temporary object are associated only with the
>   full-expression, not with any specific subexpression.

**How to comprehend "Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression ([intro.execution]) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created."?Could anyboday make it clear by some simple examples?**

Comment: For a less technical paraphrase of the documentation, see [A: Life span of temporary arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2506800). (It finally occurred to me to search for "full expression" instead of "temporary destroyed".)

Comment: It's so kind of you.I would read it right now.

Comment: As i have read the documentation aforementioned, one more question raised."`Class CTest; CTest fool(CTest);  CTest cTes = func(CTest());`" I think the temporary object(`CTest()` in `fool(CTest())`) should be destoryed after evaluating the entire expression(`CTest cTes = func(CTest());`)  and **after evaluating  the copy constructor(`CTest  cTes=`)**.Am i right?Thank you.

Comment: You've entered one of the places where the terminology gets weird. Technically, `CTest cTes = func(CTest());` is not an "expression", but it is a "full-expression", as crazy as that sounds. So, yes, the temporary is destroyed after the copy construction.

Comment: @JaMiT Amazing!What are the differences between "expresssion" and "full-expression"?

Comment: That looks like a new question to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple example. This expression produces a temporary object:

```
std::string("test")
```

Here, that expression is used as a subexpression:

```
function(std::string("test"));
// point A
```

At point A, the temporary object has been destroyed because the point is after the full-expression where the temporary object was created.

---

Here is an example of how to write a bug if this rule is not understood:

```
const std::string& function(const std::string& arg) {
    return arg;
}

const std::string& ref = function("test");
std::cout << ref;
```

Here, the temporary object that was created as the argument is destroyed after the full expression, and therefore `ref` has become invalid - a dangling reference. The behaviour is undefined when the invalid reference is inserted into the output stream.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification.You mean the the temporary object(`std::string("test")`) is destroyed **after the return** of `function`?Could i think in this way.

Comment: @sunshilong369 Yes. The temporary object is alive through the entire function, but not alive as soon as the function has returned.

Answer (score 1):

An explanation that works in many cases is that temporary objects are destroyed when execution reaches the semicolon at the end of the statement. Some language constructs (such as a `for` loop) are not covered by this explanation, so don't push it too hard. For a better explanation of the exceptions, see [Statement that isn't a full-expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42517747/statement-that-isnt-a-full-expression).

As one example:

```
i = foo1(foo2(std::string("test")));
```

The temporary string is kept alive until after the assignment, as the assignment occurs before the end of the statement. (In this case, the full expression is the statement.)

Comment: Thank for your clarification.Asume that this is an expression that `foo1(foo2((std::string("test"))));`, do you mean the temporary object(`std::string("test")`) should be destroyed **after** the return  of the function `foo1`?

Comment: @sunshilong369 Yes.